# Java == behaving ambiguously

Tags: java

I came across this question in a Facebook group. I know I should be using `equals()` method but I want to know why this is happening

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s1="abc:5";
        String s2="abc:5";
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
        System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + s1==s2);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
true
false
```

Comment: i would expect the second line to print s1 == s2false

Comment: `System.out.println( ("s1 == s2 " + s1) == s2 );`

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I would have, too!  But it doesn't

Comment: @JeffHawthorne I would expect any respectable Java compiler to cause the result of the statement to be true because "abc:5" is a static string compiled into the class and the generated byte code should simply load the symbol into two variables. You can also try `new String("abc:5") != "abc:5"` and `new String("abc:5").intern() == "abc:5"`. The latter may or may not be true in Java 7 because `intern()` may keep the result in the heap instead of perm gen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh I just make some change in the code and get that `+` first doing `"s1 == s2 s1"` then `==` with `s2` which is not true. New code

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String s1="abc:5";
        String s2="abc:5";
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
        System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + (s1==s2));
        System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + s1==s2);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
true
s1 == s2 true
false
```

Answer (score 16):

This is due to operator precedence. '+' has a higher precedence than ==. You are actually comparing ("s1 == s2" + s1) to s2.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Answer (score 6):

The confusion is in the order of operations.  What is happening is that you're concatenating `"s1 == s2 "` and `s1`, then using `==` on that result and `s2`.

They are different objects, so `false` is printed (and `"s1 == s2"` is not printed).  Put parentheses:

```
System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + (s1==s2));
```

This will print `s1 == s2 true` because both `s1` and `s2` refer to the same interned string literal, `"abc:5"`.

Answer (score 2):

this is easy to understand once you thought about it: the 2. println first adds "s1 == s2" and your string s1 and then compares it with s2, so it outputs false, because "s1 == s2abc:5" is not "abc:5"

Answer (score 2):

It is adding the strings `"s1 == s2 " + s1` and then computing whether that is equal to `s2`. It is not so it is printing `false`.

The [Java Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) might help you here.

Answer (score 2):

I think when using "==" the system will just check if the two things share the same location in the systems memory. However, if you use the ".equals" method the system will check if the two Strings share the same characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of operator precedence of something like that, if you do         `System.out.println(""+(s1==s2));`, it will print true.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
    System.out.println(s1==s2);
    System.out.println("s1 == s2 " + s1==s2);
```

Since  s1 and s2 are the same String literals

```
`s1==s2` is true
```

Thus the code can be written as

```
    System.out.println(true);   => true
    System.out.println("true" + s1==s2);
```

Now, "true" + s1==s2 is comprehended as ("true" + s1)==s2 due to higher precedence given to "+". Thus

```
"true"+s1 => trueabc:5 and
s2 => "abc:5"
```

Hence

```
    System.out.println("true" + s1==s2); => false
```